# What is the difference between require and load in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm going through Practical Common Lisp, I'm almost finished, and one question that has not been answered for me so far (or maybe I just missed it) is the difference between "require" and "load".

So what is the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: To anyone reading this question and answers to it: _**require** and the whole modules system **is deprecated** in Common Lisp since the ANSI standardization_!.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`require` is used for modules, which can each consist of one or many files.

`load` is used to load an arbitrary single file.

> The `require` function tests whether a
>   module is already present (using a
>   case-sensitive comparison); if the
>   module is not present, require
>   proceeds to load the appropriate file
>   or set of files. The pathname
>   argument, if present, is a single
>   pathname or a list of pathnames whose
>   files are to be loaded in order, left
>   to right. If the pathname argument is
>   nil or is not provided, the system
>   will attempt to determine, in some
>   system-dependent manner, which files
>   to load. This will typically involve
>   some central registry of module names
>   and the associated file lists.

Source: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node119.html

> The `load` function loads the file named by
>   filename into the Lisp environment. It
>   is assumed that a text (character
>   file) can be automatically
>   distinguished from an object (binary)
>   file by some appropriate
>   implementation-dependent means,
>   possibly by the file type. The
>   defaults for filename are taken from
>   the variable
>   *default-pathname-defaults*. If the filename (after the merging in of the
>   defaults) does not explicitly specify
>   a type, and both text and object types
>   of the file are available in the file
>   system, load should try to select the
>   more appropriate file by some
>   implementation-dependent means.

Source: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node217.html

Comment: CLTL isn't a good primary reference for CL; the HyperSpec is better. See http://l1sp.org/cl/load or http://l1sp.org/cl/require for short links to the right places.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `(require)` loads a module if it has not been loaded already; `(load)` loads a file.

Comment: Just a guess: when we use "in-package" macro in a file with "require" it does not change the package after loading?